# (Free) Fonts similar to Zamenhof?

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm looking for a font like [Zamenhof](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/castletype/zamenhof/) for a project I'm working on, but would prefer not to have to purchase the font.

[image]

Anyone know of a similar typeface?

Comment: Are you getting paid for the project? If so, consider paying for the tools.

Comment: It's a personal project. If it was a project I was getting paid for I'd buy the font and charge it to the client... Not that I needed your moral feedback.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need it. Lots of 'designers' do, though. There's an assumption by many people out there that a) there is a free knock off of every font out there and b) there is no reason not to use the knock offs.

Comment: But one to consider might be Bender: http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=Bender It's pay-what-you-want (including nothing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Intro Inline, free for personal use
http://www.fonts2u.com/intro-inline.font

Comment: Awesome - totally the winner.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of free fonts that imitate the "Jurassic Park" font (which is actually **[Neuland Inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAvu1.gif)** - based on Neuland, a commercial font designed in 1923).

One is **[African font](http://www.fontspace.com/allen-r-walden/african)** by **Allen R. Walden** (freeware):

[image]

It's hard to find much information about where it comes from but it at least doesn't look like it's an exact copy of Neuland.

Answer (score 0):

[**Pipeline**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/letterheadfonts/lhf-pipeline/) - Not free but half the price of Zamenhof

[image]

Comment: But not similar in any way, apart from being inlined.